# Easier way to get back values from DynamoDB using SDK2 for PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

All of the methods and iterators that return results from DynamoDB seem to contain the following format (in json style):

```
{key : [TYPE,value]}
```

Where 'TYPE' is N,S...

I want them to be in the format:

```
{key : value}
```

Where 'value' is a String if S and a number if N (or an array of such if in set form).

The API contains a helper method to format attributes by type from an array:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_formatAttributes

Is there a pre-existing helper method or flag that will do the inverse for results that I've overlooked?

I know implementation of this is somewhat trivial - It just seems to be a bit of work to do the conversion every time I was to use a result.
(here is a naive version providing just the 'N' and 'S' cases)

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan',$params);
foreach($iterator as $item){
    $newitem = [];
    foreach($item as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $type => $actualv){
            switch($type){
                case 'S' :
                    $newitem[$k] = $actualv;
                    break;
                case 'N' :
                    $newitem[$k] = (int)$actualv;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($newitem).PHP_EOL;
}
```

Is there a method I overlooked to make this easier without having to loop over every key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT: Before version 2.4.1 of the SDK,] there isn't a really a pre-existing helper for this, but since your are using `getIterator`, you can use some iterators magic. Try something like this (building off your original code):

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', $params);
$iterator = new \Guzzle\Iterator\MapIterator($iterator, function ($item) {
    return array_map('current', $item);
});

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // Get a single attribute value
    echo $item['attribute_name'] . "\n";

    // Print the item attributes
    echo print_r($item);
}
```

EDIT: For version 2.4.1+, you can use the included ItemIterator class that does something similar to what I did with the MapIterator.

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Scan', $params);
$iterator = new \Aws\DynamoDb\Iterator\ItemIterator($iterator);

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // Get a single attribute value
    echo $item['attribute_name'] . "\n";

    // Print the item attributes
    echo print_r($item->toArray());
}
```

EDIT: See also [Iterating through Amazon DynamoDB Results](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/TxJGHHKBUJO1AL/Iterating-through-Amazon-DynamoDB-Results)